# Is there any limitations of std::ostream::write?

Tags: c++, memory, fstream, binaryfiles, large-files

Is there any limitations of [std::ostream::write](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ostream/ostream/write/) when we are writing big files to disk(more than 4Gb)?

For example when I write

```
ofs.write((char*)m.data, m.total()*sizeof(float));
```

can expression `m.total()*sizeof(float)` overflow? In what format I need to specify size(int,long,int64)?

What will be memory footprint of `ofs.write`, does it require some additional memory to complete operation,i.e. maybe more memory efficient to write memory block line by line?

**Update:**

I'm on ubuntu x64 but this code gives me sz < 0

```
std::streamsize sz= std::numeric_limits<int>::max()+10;
```

ok, it works like this:

```
std::streamsize sz= std::streamsize(std::numeric_limits<int>::max())+10;
```

Last question is that `m.total()` return `size_t` and how should I 
correctly and safely convert it to `std::streamsize`?

Comment: If you check e.g. [this `write` reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/write), it tells you that the size is [`std::streamsize`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/streamsize) which is a signed counterpart to [`std::size_t`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/size_t). As for the actual range, it depends on the implementation, but is *usually* a 32-bit integer on 32-bit systems, and 64-bit integer on 64-bit systems. If you want to find out, why not use e.g [`std::numeric_limits`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits) to get the ranges?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg see update, not sure how to write safe code when size of file more than `std::numeric_limits<int>::max()`.

Comment: Is there a requirement to write all of the data at once, instead of dividing it up in smaller chunks and write in a simple loop? it's not like it's going to be measurable faster anyway.

Comment: Its memory cost is zero. Write in as big chunks as you can manage.

Comment: `std::ofstream` has an internal memory buffer managed by itself.

Comment: @Lingxi what do you mean by 'internal memory buffer', please elaborate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such limitation as large files can be written chunk by chunk.

The second parameter of `std::ofstream::write` is of type `std::streamsize` about which you can find a reference [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/streamsize).

As to the memory footprint of `std::ofstream::write`, `std::ofstream` manages a buffer itself whose size is implementation-defined and irrelevant to the second parameter you passed to `std::ofstream::write`. So, the memory footprint is basically fixed. This also implies that a single call to the high-level `std::ofstream::write` with a large size (the second parameter) may result in multiple calls to some underlying write function. So, trying to put multiple `std::ofstream::write` calls into a single one does not really buy you much. You can find a reference about the internal buffer managed by `std::ofstream` [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_filebuf/setbuf).

As to your last question, the conversion is safe only if the value of the `std::size_t` variable is within the value range of `std::streamsize`. As long as this condition is met, any type conversion method will work just fine.